# Generic type instantiation different from result of mechanical replacement

Tags: typescript-generics

Can you tell me why types `U` and `W` are different below? Naively, you'd expect them to be identical: after all, I'm just mechanically replacing in the definition of `Weird` the occurrences of the type parameter `T` with the concrete type to which `Weird` is applied.

```
type Weird< T > = T extends undefined ? never : T;

type X = number | undefined;

type U = X extends undefined ? never : X;  // U is number | undefined

type W = Weird< X >;  // W is number
```

Environment: I use TS 3.7.5, but I've verified that the result is the same in TS 3.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have learned that this behavior is explained by the fact that conditional types are distributed over unions in formal type parameters of generic types. See details here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types